# Identify row by ID, then one of it's cells by class

Tags: javascript, html-table

Given this table:

```
<table border="1" width="200" id="table1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#CB2F7F">
    <tr id="st_ppp">
        <td width="60%" class="totalLabels">Price per piece</td>
        <td width="39%" align="right" class="totalElements">unknown</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="st_qty">
        <td width="60%" class="totalLabels">Quantity</td>
        <td width="39%" align="right" class="totalElements">unknown</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="60%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="39%" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="60%" class="subTotalLabel">Sub-Total:</td>
        <td width="39%" align="right" class="subTotal">unknown</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'd like to do something like the following pseudo code:

```
document.getElementById("st_ppp").[td whose class is totalElements].innerHTML="NewPrice";
document.getElementById("st_qty").[td whose class is totalElements].innerHTML="NewQty";
```

I'm open also to suggestions of any other changes to the HTML that will make the JS easier to work with.

Comment: what you need is jQuery. It's basically what you need and will open you to a whole new world of easy selectors and clever JS methods.

Comment: @ericosg There is absolutly no need to load an almost 100k lib in order to have some wrapper for native JS functionality!

Comment: @ericosg to bad one can't downvote comments...

Comment: the reason i didn't post an answer for jQuery is because i agree that it's not needed for something that can be done without too much fuss. However, the overall benefits are surely positive when it applies to more than one code segment. @Christoph, I'm actually still wondering which comment you want to down-vote :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not worried about compatibility with Internet Explorer 7 and earlier, `querySelector` is perfect for that (but if you go this way, credits to @Sirko instead):

```
document.querySelector('#st_ppp > .totalElements').innerHTML = "NewPrice";
```

If you're already using jQuery, it's excellent for that:

```
$('#st_ppp > .totalElements').text('NewPrice');
```

Otherwise, a loop will work:

```
var pricePerPiece = document.getElementById('st_ppp');
var i, c;

for(i = 0; c = pricePerPiece.children[i]; i++) {
    if((' ' + c.className + ' ').indexOf(' totalElements ') > -1) {
        c.innerHTML = 'NewPrice';
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I made a function out of this answer. I added it in an edit, but my edit was not approved. Oh Well. I did notice that if I have similarly named classes on the contained cells, it caused a problem. The easy work around is to rename that class since I have that level of flexibility in this project.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `querySelector` ([MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelector)) and the respective CSS selectors to get your elements and change their content.

```
document.querySelector( '#st_ppp .totalElements' ).innerHTML = "NewPrice";
document.querySelector( '#st_qty .totalElements' ).innerHTML = "NewQty";
```

Comment: I think you want a `#` before each of those element IDs. Also, careful - it doesn't work in IE7 and earlier.

Comment: @minitech Thanks. Missed those.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out. If (when) it works. I'll come back and accept the answer.

Comment: Worked in FF, but not in IE8. I ran into something like that before with json. Something to do with doctype if I remember correctly. I'll adapt @minitech 's solution.